# Application of an XPath query to a SOAPMessage in Java

Tags: java, xml, soap, xpath

currently making a SOAP request using Java's `SOAPConnectionFactory` and `SOAPConnection`'s `.call()` method, which returns a `SOAPMessage` object, and I would like to apply an XPath query to it. Is this at all possible, or am I going about it completely wrong?

As far as I can work out, I'd have to somehow convert `SOAPMessage` to an `InputSource` which I can then apply the XPath to, but I can't quite work out how to go about doing this.

Thanks,
Peter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SOAPBody](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/soap/SOAPBody.html) can be cast to Node. So, you can use it like this:

```
URL endpoint = new URL("http://www.webservicex.net/whois.asmx");
SOAPMessage message = connection.call(sm, endpoint);
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
xpath.setNamespaceContext(new SoapNamespaceContext());
Node resultNode = (Node) xpath.evaluate("//m:GetWhoISResult", message.getSOAPBody(), XPathConstants.NODE);
... do something with resultNode...
```

Comment: Thanks - this is almost identical to what I did in the end :-)